# Visual asset to indicate a list item can display a "details" section

Tags: icons, ux-designer

Customer specification require us to show a list of items (let's say they are a list of fruits), where only some of them are able to display a details section when the user clicks.

I'm looking for a visual asset that would make the user notice that out of all fruits, those with that visual aid can be clicked to go to a details section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a visual indicator that the element is clickable, for example a different font color or background and for example a "+" sign to expand a section for more details.

[image]

Comment: This approach is pretty common practice, but keep in mind the "plus" icon could be interpreted as an "add" or "zoom" action if it is used in that context elsewhere.

I would personally recommend using an angle/arrow/caret icon as seen in Lucas M.'s answer, as these icons typically mean that more information or content is available.

A pretty good reference for this can be found [in this article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/06/designing-perfect-accordion-checklist/)

Answer (score 4):

You could either have an icon that represents "more info", ie:

[image]

or you could have a slightly set apart list item that is just subtle enough for the user to notice:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your list of items is a collection of objects which could be represented by an icon, for instance if it is a list of fruits, they can all be displayed with a respective fruit icon. Now for fruits which can be expanded to view details, say Mango, display a variant version of the mango icon when it is hover over. (May be a bunch of mangoes, or sliced mangoes,....)

So imagine a list of fruits represented by fruit icons and as you hover over, the ones with more information to detail show a change in their display icon which gives a subtle hint to the user that there is more to this item.